# Responsive layout with nested divs using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Responsive layout with nested divs using bootstrap
Here my html code

```
  <div class="container-fluid" style="height: 350px;">
        <div class="row-fluid clearfix" style="height: 100%">
            <div class="col-md-9 column" style="height: 100%;">
                <div class="row clearfix" style="height: 50%;">
                    <div class="col-md-4 column" style="height: 100%;background-color: red">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 column" style="height: 100%;background-color: green">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 column" style="height: 100%;background-color: blue">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row clearfix" style="height: 50%;">
                    <div class="col-md-12 column" style="height: 100%;background-color: pink">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 column" style="height: 100%;background-color: yellow">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

output:

[image: Responsive layout]

while increasing the browser screen width

here the output after increasing

[image: after increasing browser size]

here green and blue colored div missing

my expected output:

[image: Expected Output]

Please help me out..

Answer (score 2):

You need to define classes for mobile view as well, otherwise elements can overlap each other. For example:

```
col-xs-12 col-md-4 column
```

See the [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/ttwKSdU74Y)

Comment: What do you mean "more specific"?

Comment: That's never going to work as on mobile your 3 divs become 100% width and overlapping each other.

Answer (score 1):

This is working now, remove clearfix class from row. here is the code

```html
   <div class="container-fluid" style="height: 350px;">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row-fluid clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-9 column">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 column" style="height: 150px;background-color: red">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 column" style="height: 150px; background-color: green">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 column" style="height: 150px; background-color: blue">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 column" style="height: 150px; background-color: pink">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 column" style="background-color: yellow; height: 300px">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Dileep Kumar** Hi there, I striped out most of your code to what is probably only needed.
See if this works for you.
This code has the pink block nest up with the others.

Here is the large view **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8w6zqLwj/embedded/result/)**. Easier  to resize.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.space {
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;  
}    
    
.block-a {
  height: 350px;  
}
.block-b {
  height: 175px; 
}    
.block-red {
  height: 175px;
  background-color:#ff1000;  
}
.block-darkgreen {
  height: 175px;   
  background-color: green;  
}
.block-blue {
  height: 175px;   
  background-color: blue;  
}
.block-pink {
  height: 175px;   
  background-color: pink;  
}
.block-darkyellow {
  height: 350px;   
  background-color: gold;
}     
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

<div class="container col-lg-12 space"></div>
    
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid col-md-9 block-a">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 block-red"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 block-darkgreen"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 block-blue"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 block-pink"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid col-md-3 block-a">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 block-darkyellow"></div>
    </div>
</div>    
    
  
    
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well of course the red one will be shown, because you have specified the height of the parent div as `50%` and all the three children with height of `100%` so the red div, which is the first one, will take up all the height. One solution would be to specify a height of `33.33%` on the three divs, when the breakpoint is reached, like:

```
@media(max-width: 767px) {
  .col-md-9 .col-md-4 {
    height: 33.33%;
  }
}
```

I'd put some more specific classes to the divs before doing this.